Discoloration around ceiling edges, what could be the reason?
What could be the reason of this coloration and the crack-like black  color at the edges and joints of the celing?


looks like spider silk catching dirt ... examine it closely

It may indeed be an open joint If so, apply plaster patching compound (spackle or equivalent) or a paintable caulk, then paint if necessary to match the adjacent wall.
Or apply a skim coat of mud, tape the corner, apply another skim coat and sand to smoothe and to feather the edges into the adjacent wall, prime and paint.
Or install molding to bridge those gaps, which is what was done at the wall/ceiling junction in my living room. (I'm my case it's just 1/2" cove, which someday I may replace with serious crown molding, perhaps with picture rail.)
Or just stop looking that closely. It's not ideal, but it's nothing serious.
